# My sendemail.php contact form is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email, xampp

I am trying to test this sendEmail.php script with XAMPP but it is not working. I believe the script is good but I am not sure if I am testing it in correct way. I changed the e-mail address in the php script (below) to my own e-mail, filled the contact form and pressed 'send' button but the message never reaches my inbox. The loader is spinning all the time but nothing happens.

I also tried to change blank action='' into action='inc/sendEmail.php' in HTML code but nothing happens. I started XAMPP and copy/pasted all the documents in htdocs folder. The page loads normally when I access it through localhost but besides the loader spinning all the time, I never receive any confirmation that my message is sent (or not) and it never reaches my inbox. There is a small ajax snippet at the bottom. Can that be the problem? Can Ajax be tested with XAMPP or maybe this is not the way to test this form via XAMPP? I would appreciate if someone could help me to make this work. Thank you for your time!

As my PHP code is significantly different than other codes I found on Stackoverflow I still cannot figure out the answer? Could anyone please point me in the right direction? I would really like to use this code not some other. Thanks.

Here is the sendEmail.php:

```
<?php

// Replace this with your own email address
$siteOwnersEmail = 'user@website.com';


if($_POST) {

$fname = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactFname']));
$lname = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactLname']));
$email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
$subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
$contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

// Check First Name
if (strlen($fname) < 2) {
        $error['fname'] = "Please enter your first name.";
}
// Check Last Name
if (strlen($lname) < 2) {
    $error['lname'] = "Please enter your last name.";
}
// Check Email
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
    $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
}
// Check Message
if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
    $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
}
// Subject
if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }

// Set Name
$name = $fname . " " . $lname;

// Set Message
$message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
$message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
$message .= "Message: <br />";
$message .= $contact_message;
$message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";

// Set From: header
$from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

// Email Headers
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


if (!$error) {

  ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
  $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
  else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }

} # end if - no validation error

else {

    $response = (isset($error['fname'])) ? $error['fname'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['lname'])) ? $error['lname'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;

    echo $response;

} # end if - there was a validation error

}

?>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<section id="contact">
    <h1 align="center">GET IN TOUCH WITH US<span>.</span></h1>
    <hr />

    <div class="row form-section">
        <div id="contact-form" class="twelve columns">
            <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="">
                <fieldset>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="six columns mob-whole">
                            <label for="contactFname">First Name <span class="required">*</span></label>                                   
                                <input name="contactFname" type="text" id="contactFname" placeholder="First Name" value="" />                           
                        </div>
                        <div class="six columns mob-whole"> 
                            <label for="contactLname">Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label>                                
                                <input name="contactLname" type="text" id="contactLname" placeholder="Last Name" value="" />                            
                        </div>                          
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="six columns mob-whole"> 
                            <label for="contactEmail">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>                                
                                <input name="contactEmail" type="text" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Email" value="" />                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="six columns mob-whole">  
                            <label for="contactSubject">Subject</label>                                
                                <input name="contactSubject" type="text" id="contactSubject" placeholder="Subject"  value="" />                         
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="twelve columns">
                            <label  for="contactMessage">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <textarea name="contactMessage"  id="contactMessage" placeholder="Your Message" rows="10" cols="50" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button class="submit full-width">Send Message</button>
                        <div id="image-loader">
                            <img src="images/loader.gif" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </fieldset>

            </form> <!-- /contactForm -->

            <!-- message box -->
            <div id="message-warning"></div>
            <div id="message-success">
               <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Your message was sent, thank you!<br />
            </div>

        </div> <!-- /contact-form -->       
    </div> <!-- /form-section -->     

</section>  <!-- /contact-->
```

Here is JavaScript/Ajax code:

```
$('form#contactForm button.submit').on('click', function() {

  $('#image-loader').fadeIn();

  var contactFname = $('#contactForm #contactFname').val();
  var contactLname = $('#contactForm #contactLname').val();
  var contactEmail = $('#contactForm #contactEmail').val();
  var contactSubject = $('#contactForm #contactSubject').val();
  var contactMessage = $('#contactForm #contactMessage').val();

  var data = 'contactFname=' + contactFname  + '&contactLname=' + contactLname + 
             '&contactEmail=' + contactEmail + '&contactSubject=' + contactSubject + 
             '&contactMessage=' + contactMessage;

  $.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      url: "inc/sendEmail.php",
      data: data,
      success: function(msg) {

        // Message was sent
        if (msg == 'OK') {
           $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
           $('#message-warning').hide();
           $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
           $('#message-success').fadeIn();   
        }
        // There was an error
        else {
           $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
           $('#message-warning').html(msg);
            $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
        }

      }

  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: My PHP code is significantly different so I still cannot figure out the answer? Could anyone please point me in the right direction? I would really like to use this code not some other. Thanks.

Comment: As for right direction, I'd suggest you to stop writing code this way. You can pick any framework and start writing with it. Your situation is like writing JavaScript common code without jquery. As for sending mails, your code might work correctly on your local machine, but on some hosting providers it will fail. Use a well-tested and stable mail library for that, which is called SwiftMailer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will check SwiftMailer. I am not good with php so I just wanted to know how to test this code and if it works properly.